# Load, render and animate 3D rigged models in Flash (or propose alternative)

Tags: html, flash, cross-browser, unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4

I have some rigged 3D models (made in MAX) with full skeletal animation which I need to load and render in real-time in a browser window.

I am thinking of using Flash *(Stage3D?)* because:

- I am an Actionscript expert
- Flash is available out-of-the-box for the vast majority of computers (or is it?)

**Is there a ready-made engine for Flash (freeware or not) that can load/render/animate MAX models?**

***Alternatively***, is there another - ***easy*** - way to go, which ***wouldn't require*** the user to download a browser plug-in (like *Unity Webplayer*)? Here are some alternatives that spring to my mind:

- WebGL (a ready-made engine would surely be needed)
- Java (same as above)
- Unity HTML5?!
- Unreal Engine 4?!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import 3D models in to flash. But each view will be a new frame.

I'd recommend not using flash for your purpose.

You can look into [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org/) which is an open-source framework and runtime for 3D graphics on the Web.